# How can I find out how many products were sold in each month?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with products with structure like this:

```
{   _id: 01,
    user_id: 10,
    line_items: [
      { 
        _id: 2,
        quantity: 2,
      },
      { 
        _id: 3,
        quantity:  1,
      }
    ],
    purchase_date: 2021-02-05T21:00:00.000+00:00
  }
```

How can I find out how many products were sold in each month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out how many line items were sold each month, you need to run an aggregation where the pipeline consists of a [`$group`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. The group by key will be the month value returned by the [`$month`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) operator on the purchase_date field. The count will consist of the [`$sum`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator on another [`$sum`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of the array of quantities returned by the expression `"$line_items.quantity"` which essentially is interpreted as in the above document

```
{ $sum: [2, 1] } => 3
```

So your overall pipeline follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
      _id: {
        "$month": "$purchase_date"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: {
          $sum: "$line_items.quantity"
        }
      }
  } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ehXEYdoC8WS)

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain why do we use two $sum there?

Comment: The inner `$sum` can act on an array of integers (which this returned from this expression `"$line_items.quantity"`) to give the sum total for the current document and in this case it's 3. The outer `$sum` will then aggregate all the documents in the month group to get the total.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 The easiest and faster is this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $group: {
     _id: {
       "$substr": [
         "$purchase_date",
         0,
         7
       ]
    },
     count: {
       $sum: 1
     }
   }
 }
])
```

Explained:

Group by the first 7 characters that include year and month: "2021-12" and count the products.

[playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/On0TkaBENwl)

Option 2: Convert string to date/month:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      $month: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$purchase_date"
        }
      }
     },
     count: {
       $sum: 1
     }
   }
  }
 ])
```

Explained:

Convert the string to month and group

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qwlohnuVpCz)